# Mac download manager that supports login and recovery options?

Tags: macos, download-manager

I login to this site to download files, and my Internet connection keeps going out.

Is there a Mac download manager that can download these files, and have recovery options?

My files are like 2GB and its a real pain.

Comment: You could give http://jdownloader.org/ a try, but it's probably not exactly what you want and incredibly slow on Macs. It supports recovery though.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out Speed Download](http://www.yazsoft.com/products/speed-download/). It will depend on the server you're connecting to, but in general it handles logins and resuming well.

Answer (score 0):

[DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/) is a download manager that runs as a Firefox extension. works great on a Mac.

> DownThemAll lets you download all the links or images contained in a
>   webpage and much more: you can refine your downloads by fully
>   customizable criteria to get only what you really want.